# Intellij idea plugin inspection block build

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I created my plugin for Intellij idea, which searches some specific error by inspection.

Inspection type is Error. But it doesn't block build.

Is there way to block build and show compile error?

Comment: IDE inspections don't affect on javac build process.

Comment: @y.berdov I have already found it,  I ask possible way to do it

Comment: @RodGers, there is a slack-channel where the community of plugin developers can help you. Just send a request them https://plugins.jetbrains.com/slack